# Sorting by "aggregation type: count" is not working

Tags: views, css-js-aggregation, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to solve this problem: [Drupal 7 Most Popular Tags in a list as a block: How?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7414/drupal-7-most-popular-tags-in-a-list-as-a-block-how) with Views 7.x-3.0-rc1.

The solution is [the answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7414/drupal-7-most-popular-tags-in-a-list-as-a-block-how/9116#9116) by [Dylan Tack](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/1711/dylan-tack).

> - create a view of terms
> - add a required relationship to "content using tags"
> - set use aggregation: yes
> - add the "term name" field a second time, set one of the to "aggregation type: count"
> - add "term name" as a sort criteria, set "aggregation type: count"
>
> A sample view is at http://drupalbin.com/19467

It works until I try to sort the list; in that case, I get an error when adding a sort criteria. If I set "aggregation type: count" the sort-criteria changes to "Broken/missing handler" and it is not sorting.

Do you have any idea? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hello, anonym-developer; welcome on _Drupal Answers_, and in general to Stack Exchange. Your previous post has been deleted because you posted as answer something that is not an answer; you were asking a question, which (by definition) is not an answer. SE sites are not forums; you can post as answer what is effectively an answer. This also means you cannot post as answer what should be a comment.

Comment: seems to be a bug:[link](http://drupal.org/node/1203994#comment-4860346)

Comment: this issue is solved in the dev version. [7.x-3.x-dev](http://drupal.org/node/608852)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved in the development snapshot version [7.x-3.x-dev](http://drupal.org/node/608852).